# Number Columns instead of pages in KOMA-Script (index-friendly)

Tags: koma-script, two-column

In KOMA-Script's `twocolumn` option, is there a way to reset `thepage` to increment on each column (ie twice per page)? I tried making a new counter that incremented at the right and left heads, but unfortunately that didn't work for indexing.